# How to retrieve/store DB values in Load Runner?

Tags: loadrunner, vugen

I have an Oracle SQL Developer installed in my machine and able to connect/query Database.

Now, I need to connect database via Load Runner, write SQL query in vugen script, retrieve database column values, store it to parameter, which then I can substitute into my web_custom_requests.

Any help on this is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Read the section in the manual on creation of Oracle virtual users.

Read the section on multiprotocol virtual users.

You are adding load that is not present in production.  This is not recommended.   Export the data you need and place it in a file or virtual table server.

Comment: My database table values will change frequently, hence I need to retrieve data dynamically from DB via load runner script. I need to connect to DB(SQL Browser) via Load runner and retrieve values that will be substituted into my script. Any other suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: Not recommended.  You will be using queries that are not there in production and very likely unoptimized.   Expect table scans, pessimistic locks, etc...

Export the data you need before your test to data files.   If you have a script which is creating data that is a consumed by another script, then have the publisher place it on a VTS queue for the consumer to pick it up